# Trouble with loops python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def startsWith (word, lst):
    u=0
    x=0
    w=len(word)
    while u < len(lst):
        lest = lst[u]
        while x < len(word):
            if word[x].lower() == lest[x]:
                x=x+1
            if word[x].upper() == lest[x]:
                x=x+1

        print (lst[u])
        u=u+1
```

What I want to get something that identifies if a particular list item starts with the same letters as the "word" string. Whenever I try a trial run, if always says:

```
    >>> startsWith ('app',['apple','Apple','APPLE','pear','ApPle'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#92>", line 1, in <module>
    startsWith ('app',['apple','Apple','APPLE','pear','ApPle'])
  File "C:/Users/gpersaud/Desktop/hw3.py", line 35, in startsWith
    if word[x].upper() == lest[x]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

The second if will have an `x` value after the last one x reaches the end of the word

```
if word[x].upper() == lest[x]:
```

Replace it with

```
if word[x].lower() == lest[x]:
    x=x+1
elif word[x].upper() == lest[x]:
    x=x+1
```

or

```
if word[x].lower() == lest[x] or word[x].upper() == lest[x]:
    x=x+1
```

Comment: A more compact comparison would be `word[x].upper() == lest[x].upper()` (though since both of those methods work on whole strings rather than only single characters, you might be able to call them on a longer substring). There are other potential issues. If `lest` is shorter than `word`, you'll still get an `IndexError`. And `x` never gets reset to `0`, so most list items after the first will only have some middle letters checked (and those shorter than the longest item ahead of them in the list will not be checked at all). If you need to loop by character, I'd use a `for` loop and `zip`.